# Basic C# GUI crashes in main

Tags: c#, c++

I have a very basic unmanaged C++ project, C++/CLI wrapper and C# GUI. I've built all 3 projects as x64. I try and run the C# project and I get the following exception:

> First-chance exception at 0x000007fefd84cacd in TestAppGUI.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException * __ptr64 at memory
>   location 0x0057b498.

Does anyone know what could be causing the issue?

These are my classes:

Test.h (unmanaged code)

```
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )

#include <iostream>

namespace Test
{
    class DllExport BasicTest
    {
    public:
        BasicTest();
        ~BasicTest();
    };
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

Test::BasicTest::BasicTest()
{

}

Test::BasicTest::~BasicTest()
{

}
```

TestCLR.h (wrapper)

```
// TestCLR.h

#pragma once

#include "../TestApp/Test.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace Test;

namespace TestCLR {

    public ref class Class1
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    public:
        Class1();

    private:
        BasicTest *bsTest;
    };
}
```

TestCLR.cpp

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "TestCLR.h"

TestCLR::Class1::Class1()
{
    bsTest = new BasicTest();
}
```

TestAppGUI Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TestCLR;

namespace TestAppGUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Class1 obj = new Class1();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to get a native C++ program to execute managed code.  You picked the worst possible way, you cannot diagnose managed exceptions this way.  Change the Debugger Type from Auto to Mixed to get ahead temporarily.  When this happens on the user's machine, you'll get a very difficult support call.  You'll be clueless how to provide assistance, just as you are now.

Comment: The debugger type is disabled. I can't change it...